# adt eclipse error finding path to jre

Tags: java, eclipse, adt

I extracted ADT and when I'm trying to run eclipse get a error,

"A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Devolpment Kit (JDK)
must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following location:
C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe
javaw.exe in your current PATH"

I've installed JDK 7, but still not working. how do I fix this?

Comment: do you have `JAVA_HOME`, `ANDROID_HOME` and `PATH` environment variables properly set?

Comment: No I don't. idk how to do that. can u help me with that?

Comment: [Check this](https://sites.google.com/site/richgossweiler/home/android-development-notes/installing-the-android-sdk-on-windows)